# what's the proper syntax to insert a multi-line substitution string and apply it toward a single array value?

Tags: perl

Here's the scenario -- One step of the process involves fixing city names when the data is obviously misspelled, along with some basic conversions like "MTN" to "Mountain" and so forth.  I've built a variable containing several substitution strings, and I'm trying to apply that set of subs on one of the input fields later down the line.

```
my $citysub = <<'EOF'; 
s/DEQUEEN/DE QUEEN/; 
s/ELDORADO/EL DORADO/; 
...                # there are about 100 such substitution strings 
EOF 
... 
while ($line <INFILE>) 
{ 
... 
@field = split(/","/,$line);                # it's a comma-delimited file with quoted strings; this is spltting exactly like I intend; at the end, I'll piece it back together properly 
... 
# the 9th field and 12th field are city names, i.e., $field[8] and $field[12] 
$field[8] =~ $citysub;        # this is what I'm wanting to do, but it doesn't work! 
# since that doesn't work, I'm using the following, but it's much slower, obviiously 
$field[8] = `echo $field[8]|sed -e "$citysub"`;        # external calls to system commands
```

So, what's the proper syntax to insert a multi-line substitution string and apply it toward a single array value?

Answer (score -1):

```
my %citysub = ( "DEQUEEN" => "DE QUEEN", "ELDORADO" => "EL DORADO" );
for my $find ( keys %citysub ) {
    my $replace = $citysub{ $find };
    $field[8] =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
}
```

Explanation: Create a hash of "thing to match" => "thing to replace with". then loop over that hash and run s/// with the thing to match and the thing to replace with.